# How to get/insert parent tag inside child tag when we do XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

```
          <!-- Input XML -->
      <v2:College>
           <v2:Student>Name1</v2:Student>
           <v2:Student>Name2</v2:Student>
           <v2:Student>Name3</v2:Student>
           <v2:Teacher>
              <v2:Class>
                 <v2:Subject>ABC</v2:Subject>  
              </v2:Class>
           </v2:Teacher>
     </v2:College>


<!-- XSLT Transformation so far i did -->    
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="..." xmlns:ns0="...">
     <xsl:template match="/">
     <!-- <xsl:variable name="Student" select="ns0:College/ns0:Student"/> -->
         <xsl:for-each select="ns0:College"> 
            <v2:College>
                <xsl:for-each select="ns0:Student">
                    <v2:Student>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </v2:Student>
                </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="ns0:College/ns0:Teacher/ns0:Class">
            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:Subject">
                    <v2:Subject>
                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </v2:Subject>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </xsl:for-each> 
        </v2:College>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

<!-- I am expecting output as -->
     <v2:College>
           <v2:Student>Name1</v2:Student>
           <v2:Student>Name2</v2:Student>
           <v2:Student>Name3</v2:Student>
           <v2:Teacher>
              <v2:Class>
                 <v2:Subject>ABC</v2:Subject>
                  <!-- Same no of Student should come here -->                   
                 <v2:Student>Name1</v2:Student>
                 <v2:Student>Name2</v2:Student>
                 <v2:Student>Name3</v2:Student>                  
              </v2:Class>
           </v2:Teacher>
     </v2:College>
```

Note:Three Student Name(Name1,Name2,Name3) currently not coming under class element..Also i have declared a variable where i am storing the value of student name. please give me suggestion how i could get this or i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Given the following **well-formed** input:

**XML**

```
<v2:College xmlns:v2="http://example.com/v2">
   <v2:Student>Name1</v2:Student>
   <v2:Student>Name2</v2:Student>
   <v2:Student>Name3</v2:Student>
   <v2:Teacher>
      <v2:Class>
         <v2:Subject>ABC</v2:Subject>  
      </v2:Class>
   </v2:Teacher>
</v2:College>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:v2="http://example.com/v2">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="v2:Class">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="/v2:College/v2:Student"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<v2:College xmlns:v2="http://example.com/v2">
   <v2:Student>Name1</v2:Student>
   <v2:Student>Name2</v2:Student>
   <v2:Student>Name3</v2:Student>
   <v2:Teacher>
      <v2:Class>
         <v2:Subject>ABC</v2:Subject>
         <v2:Student>Name1</v2:Student>
         <v2:Student>Name2</v2:Student>
         <v2:Student>Name3</v2:Student>
      </v2:Class>
   </v2:Teacher>
</v2:College>
```

Replace `"http://example.com/v2"` with the actual namespace used by your XML.

Comment: Thank u @michael.hor257k . But what i want is only <Student> element not any other.if there is more child tag then that also coming in output. and also i want to print like  <v2:Class>
         <v2:Subject>ABC</v2:Subject>
         <v2:Student>Name1</v2:Student>
         <v2:Student>Name2</v2:Student>
         <v2:Student>Name3</v2:Student>
      </v2:Class>

Comment: @DEV I don't understand your comment. Please edit your question and provide an example where "*there is more child tag*".